# Failing to log in via publickey ssh

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm trying to set up public key login with ssh, something I've done before without difficulty.  However, this time I'm still being prompted for a password and I don't know why.  I've found tons of solutions to this problem, but none of them seem to apply to me.

Here is how my localhost is set up:

```
drwx------  2 dave dave 4096 Mar  3 20:41 .
drwx------ 20 dave dave 4096 Mar  3 19:52 ..
-rw-------  1 dave dave 1675 Mar  3 20:12 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 dave dave  385 Mar  3 20:12 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 dave dave  444 Mar  3 20:07 known_hosts
```

Here is how my remote host is set up:

```
drwx------ 2 git git 4096 Mar  3 20:33 .
drwxr-x--- 4 git git 4096 Mar  3 20:13 ..
-rw------- 1 git git  770 Mar  3 20:41 authorized_keys
```

I try and connect with the following command (for debug):

```
ssh git@10.2.1.1 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -vvv -p 222
```

The server (in debug mode produces):

```
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 222.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 811
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.1.2.2 port 51832 on 10.2.1.1 port 222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 11031
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 107:65534 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 107/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7fbe0707c550(99)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug2: kex_derive_keys [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user git service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 811
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for git [preauth]
debug3: mm_start_pam entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 100 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 100
debug1: PAM: initializing for "git"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.1.2.2"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug1: userauth-request for user git service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7fbe0707c2c0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1002/1002 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA 9c:1a:ac:a7:a2:66:63:30:97:9d:02:28:4b:4e:5e:66
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7fbe0707c2c0 is allowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Postponed publickey for git from 10.1.2.2 port 51832 ssh2 [preauth]
```

This is the output of the client:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.2.1.1 [10.2.1.1] port 222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug1: Authenticating to 10.2.1.1:222 as 'git'
debug3: put_host_port: [10.2.1.1]:222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4t4CmmuHE5EwyaYDleCj9h99kxQTeJrLcNGOOC2wMAU
debug3: put_host_port: [10.2.1.1]:222
debug3: put_host_port: [10.2.1.1]:222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.2.1.1
debug1: Host '10.2.1.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dave/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x5571a91c1f60), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:Jn4FQWeVvzzM/ybsRJYRvQYW8Ofjs9lEAEseol7l5b4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:Jn4FQWeVvzzM/ybsRJYRvQYW8Ofjs9lEAEseol7l5b4
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@10.2.1.1's password:
```

Auth logs on the server don't show any errors.  I'm not running selinux.  I think my permissions are right.  I'm running Ubuntu on the localhost and debian on the server (if it matters).

As best I can tell, everything worked (it says matching key found and all).  But I still get a password prompt.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does `authorized_keys` on the remote side contain the contents of `id_rsa.pub` from the local side? Also, the `-i` option is used to specify an identity file, `id_rsa` or similar private file, not `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Yes.  The two files hash to the same value.

Comment: So, how do I tell ssh client which key to use?  Should I be using -i still and specifying the private key instead?  (Still doesn't work with -i and private key specified.)

Comment: Just to clarify, at the top of your post, we're looking at `/home/dave/.ssh/` for the localhost files, and `/home/git/.ssh/` for the remote files, right? Because you're using `ssh git@remotehost...`

It looks like the remote `authorized_keys`, at 770 bytes, is big enough to hold 2 `.pub` files of 385 bytes, so I don't see how they could hash to the same value.

As to your question, you should use `-i` with a private key, but you normally shouldn't *have* to. That is puzzling.

Comment: You are correct.  I took a line out before I hashed (the same line was in there twice).  They are now equal and hash to the same value, but still no luck.

Comment: So...I just fixed it with the following command: ln -s ./id_rsa ./id_dsa.  It seems the client doesn't know how to find the private key.

Comment: Good that it works, but seems weird that you had to fix it that way.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way now to make ssh client look for the right file.  It looks like it tries dha, ecdsa, ed25519, but never rsa.

Comment: In your `/etc/ssh_config`, do you have `IdentitiesOnly` and/or some `IdentityFile` entries? See ssh_config(5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh git@10.2.1.1 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -vvv -p 222
```

That seems wrong: `-i` is for referencing the *private* key, not the public one:

```
ssh git@10.2.1.1 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv -p 222
```

Comment: Sharp eyes you have!

Comment: I was sure I had tried the private key as well, but tried it again after  jamieguinan mentioned it and I do have that working.

Now I just need to get it working without using -i.  Setting the IdentityFile in the config doesn't seem to be working.  That's a separate issue, though, so I'm marking this answered.